# tasty dishes vs delicious meals

Tags: difference, adjectives

Is there some difference in these phrases or not?

> **tasty dishes**

vs

> **delicious meals**

Maybe "delicious meals" are more tasty than "tasty dishes"?

Are "Dishes" and "meals" absolutely interchangeable in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Tasty' is informal, casual or conversational; 'delicious' is more formal.  A meal may consist of one or more dishes - a meal of soup, curry and rice, and pudding is a meal of three dishes.